# htaccess gives 500 - Internal Server Error

Tags: .htaccess, internal-server-error, .htpasswd

I am protecting a html file with htaccess and htpasswd. When I try accessing it, after putting  both user and password, instead of loading the "index.html" file I get a "500 - Internal Server Error"

```
AuthName "Restricted Area" 
AuthType Basic 
AuthUserFile home/folder/index.html/.htpasswd 
AuthGroupFile /dev/null 
require valid-user
```

Any suggestions? 
Maybe something with the hosting service?

Comment: Suggestion: find your error log file and learn how to use it :)

Comment: Is your AuthUserFile correct? I'd think it should be something like AuthUserFile home/folder/.htpasswd

Comment: Thanks blamonet, but it didn't help.
I'm looking into Mr. Millwoods suggestion.

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19060586/htaccess-htpasswd-500-internal-server-error

Answer (score 5):

First of all, consult the error-log (usually located in `/var/log/apache2/error.log`) to see the exact cause of the error.

If you do not have access to it, check the following:

- is this technique supported by the server? (ask your provider or admin)
- is `AuthUserFile` correct? It seems to be missing a slash and the directory is unusual. I would have suspected something like `AuthUserFile /home/webuser/sitefolder/.htpasswd`.
- change the group-file to `AuthGroupFile None` instead of pointing apache to read `/dev/null`. Think of `/dev/null` as a bottom-less trashcan. It's not easy to get anything from there and might be a reason for the server to fail trying.
- change the case of your require to `Require valid-user`. It needs to be a capital R.

To sum up:

```
AuthName "Restricted Area" 
AuthType Basic 
AuthUserFile /home/webuser/sitefolder/.htpasswd 
AuthGroupFile None
Require valid-user
```

For further info, I recommend http://httpd.apache.org/docs/.

Comment: Thank you kronn,

My hosting provider (1and1) told me that there is no error-log, that I need to create it and upload it (where?) my self. 

I just wanted to make a website, and now I end up being forced to learn some server issues.. frustrating to say the least..

Is there any simple way to learn (or do) this?

Comment: That sounds horrible, from your point of view. I would start by tweaking the `.htaccess`-file. Try to find the smallest version. the `AuthGroupFile` is not needed, for example. You can also try to experiment on your local machine. For every major OS, there is an easy to use installer for Apache, PHP and so on. One example would be [XAMPP](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp.html), however I am quite sure that there are many more. I dug a little trough the FAQ of 1and1.com and can understand your frustation. They should be able to tell you where an error.log is recognized automatically. HTH

Answer (score 0):

I know the question is a little old, but for those struggling to find the answer, make sure the path to AuthUserFile is correct and access to the .htpasswd file is set to 0655.

The file is being read by the user associated with the .htaccess file. If that user cannot execute it (i.e. if it's set to 644, etc.), the server cannot read the file to authenticate it and you get a permissions error, i.e. an Error 500.

Answer (score 0):

Now this question is older *still*, but I thought I'd also chime in because I didn't find the solution that eventually worked for me anywhere. Besides, it *is* still unanswered.

I too was getting a 500 error on my password .htaccess, and according to the error log, it was due to an "AuthName takes one argument" problem. After pounding my head against this for way too long, I finally noticed I had "curly" quotes around the AuthName, as opposed to the correct straight quotes. I replaced these, confident that I had fixed my issue.

Still, 500. Nearly threw my laptop out the window. At this point my code looked like this:

```
# PW PROTECT INT DIRECTORY
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Login"
AuthUserFile /home/mywebsite/mywebsite.com/reports/int/.htpasswd
require valid-user
```

Six ways till Sunday later, as a desperate hail Mary, I removed a comment I had diligently included at the very top of the file (gotta include those comments). That did it, 500 resolved. Finally.

I can't speak to why this was parsed as an AuthName problem in the error logs, but I think my problem all came down to trying to copy/paste the code through a less-than-ideal "plain text" editor (in this case, Apple's TextEdit, which was also responsible for those cute curly quotes, present even in plain text mode). This is an error I'll not be repeating.

I don't know if the "#" hash character is somehow goofy in TextEdit, or if there's some issue with line 1 being a comment, amounting to a blank line (not seen that anywhere), but removing the comment line did it (if anyone knows why, I'd love to hear it).

Comment: In this vast bottomless abyss of the internet, after spending way too much time than I think was justified, (although less than you), I found the fix to the 500 internal error. All it took was to open the htaccess file in textwrangler, instead of textedit (in which I created it) and change those damn quotes.  I mean, who would have thought... curly quotes???? Thank god for dudes like you... Thanks again. :)