# .htaccess/.htpasswd 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I'm working on blocking a folder with .htaccess, which I've never used before, and I'm having some trouble. Here's what I have

.htaccess (located in the folder I want blocked):

```
AuthName "Username and password required"
AuthUserFile /.htpasswd 
Require valid-user
AuthType Basic
```

.htpasswd (located at root, password is encrypted in actual file):

```
   tim:blah
```

I'm getting 500 Internal Server errors with this and I can't figure out why.

Comment: To you what is `/.htpasswd`, a file inside `/home/youraccout/public_html` or actually located on the main directory of the file system `/`?

Comment: What does your apache error logs say?

Comment: I can't access error logs through my host =( and my .htpasswd file is in the uppermost folder I can access, it's not in my pubic_html folder

Answer (score 166, accepted):

Most likely problem is this line:

```
AuthUserFile /.htpasswd
```

This line should provide full filesystem path to the password file e.g.

```
AuthUserFile /var/www/.htpasswd
```

To discover your filesystem path, you can create a PHP document containing

`echo $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];`

Comment: .htpasswd is in the uppermost folder that I can access

Comment: Also make sure `.htpasswd` is not writeable by group and others.

Comment: Found the home path. My host kind of hides essential information from me. Thanks.

Comment: My initial slash was missing, i.e. "var/www" when it should have been "/var/www". But why can't I find anything in the error log?

Comment: Thanks! In my case `echo getcwd();` got me the (wrong) relative path. `echo $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];` worked well!

Comment: OK guys, this worked: I got the auth window opening up and logged in, but then got Internal Server Error.  So I used the absolute path, solved.  BUT, for the record, this is awful!  I can't put this file in a `git` repo anymore because I can't use relative paths.  Thanks Obama, thanks Trump! (relax, a little political humor :)

Comment: The internal server error problem solved using that echo function and setting path to the file. It works!

Answer (score 12):

If nothing helped and you're using PHP you can make it work by putting this in your index.php (on top):

```
if (isset($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'], $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW'])) {
    if ($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'] !== 'user' || 
        $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW'] !== 'pass') {

        header('WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="Protected area"');
        header('HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized');

        die('Login failed');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Permissions can cause this issue too.

Make sure `.htpasswd` is readable by the web server user.

For instance, if you use nginx check the `nginx.conf` to find out what the server user is, if you use Apache you can find it out [this way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/827327/can-i-find-which-user-the-web-server-is-being-run-as-in-php), etc.

Then set the right owners and read permissions to `.htpasswd`

Answer (score 3):

If you see `500 Internal Server error` these days - it's mostly due to the fact that in newer Apache versions the path in `AuthUserFile` has to be put inside `quotation marks`.

```
AuthUserFile "/var/www/somewhere/.htpasswd"
```

Comment: Works fine for me

Answer (score 1):

I have got same problem on Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS).

It turned out that Apache has some bug (https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=54735), and you need to set password from console like this:

`htpasswd -nb username newpassw > <path-to>/.htpasswd`

Answer (score 0):

I would also add that some on some Web hosts, the .htpasswd file will not work if placed in a publicly accessible area. A recent installation I did confirmed this. As others have noted, it's best to place this in the root of the site.

Comment: "...best to place this in the root of the site" - Your last sentence appears to contradict your first (assuming by "root" you mean the _document root_)? As you suggest, this file should ideally be outside of the publicly accessible area. eg. _above_ the document root.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem, it had to do with access! Have you given ownership of the password file to `www-data` user through

```
chown www-data /var/www/.htpasswd
chmod 640 /var/www/.htpasswd
```

?  It's best to keep the password, for obvious reasons, to keep the password somewhere outside the `/var/www/` directory, let's say `/home/MYSERVER/` in such a case you also need to give ownership of this parent directory to the user `www-data`.

Answer (score 0):

Solved in .htaccess remove quote " and write full path for AuthUserFile then it will work.

Tested on xampp

```
AuthName "Restricted Area" 
AuthType Basic 
AuthUserFile C:/xampp/htdocs/.htpasswd 
AuthGroupFile /
Require valid-user
```

.htpasswd

```
foo:bar
```